# "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable" Error using org.json

Tags: java, arrays, json, org.json

```
JSONArray historyJson = new JSONArray(nameHistoryResponse);
    for (Object o : historyJson) {
        index++;
        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) o;
        String name = jsonObj.getString("name");
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(data[2].toString())) {
            foundIndex = index;
        }
    }
```

I keep getting an error on line two, saying that historyJson must be "java.lang.Iterable" but according to my code it is. Im completely stumped it would mean the world if someone had a fix for this as the project needs to be done within the next 2 hours.

Comment: doesn't seem like `JSONArray` implements `Iterable`, try to use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: I am using a for loop, do you mean replace historyJson with nameHistoryResponse?

Comment: technically speaking, you're using an _enhanced for loop_ which is different to the for loop I've suggested. see the suggested duplicates for the answer to your problem.